# How to add a button which can close webchat page?

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I'm using webchat V3 and bot framework V3.
Is it possible to send users a button which could close the webchat page?

Comment: Marking the solution as accepted serves the greater Stack Overflow community and anyone with a similar question. If you feel my or @Steven Kanberg's answer's was sufficient, please "accept" it. If not, let us know how else we can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, here is the v3 solution. The key elements are `.filter` and `.subscribe`. Filter listens to incoming activities from the bot to the page. Subscribe listens to activities and events on the page allowing you to act on them before sending data to the bot.

This example is "using" TJ's hero card of type 'imBack'. Alternatively, if you don't want text posted by the bot to the user showing the selection you can send a 'postBack'. In this case, the value is not displayed and will require you to filter on slightly different activity properties (`channelData` and `value`).

Please note, I am instantiating direct line here by including the secret for simplicity's sake. In production, you will want to exchange your secret for a token to mitigate any security issues.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Bot Chat</title>

  <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <style>
    #botchat {
      border: 1px solid #333;
      float: left;
      height: 600px;
      position: relative;
      width: 460px;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="botchat"></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>

  <script>
    const params = BotChat.queryParams(location.search);

    const user = {
      id: params['userid'] || 'userid',
      name: params['username'] || 'username'
    };

    const bot = {
      id: 'bot',
      name: 'bot'
    };

    window['botchatDebug'] = params['debug'] && params['debug'] === 'true';

    const botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
      secret: 'xxxxxxx'
    });

    BotChat.App({
      bot: bot,
      botConnection: botConnection,
      user: user
    }, document.getElementById('botchat'));

    botConnection.activity$
      .filter(function (activity) {
        if (activity.type === 'message' && activity.text === 'close' ) {
          window.close();
        }
      })
      .subscribe(function (activity) {
        // Make function calls and track activity/events from the page to the bot
      });

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope of help!

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this is possible in Web Chat v3; however, in Web Chat v4 you can use the card action middleware to change the actions default behavior. Then from the bot you can send a card with a button to close the window.

**Web Chat v4**

```
const cardActionMiddleware = () => next => card => {
  const { cardAction: { value }} = card;
  if (value === 'close') {
    window.close();
  }
  next(card);
}

window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
  cardActionMiddleware,
  directLine
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

**Bot Framework SDK v4 (Node)**

```
const card = CardFactory.heroCard(
  'Close Window',
  null,
  CardFactory.actions([
    {
      type: 'imBack',
      title: 'close',
      value: 'Close'
    }])
);

await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [card] });
```

Note, Web Chat v3 is currently in sunset and no longer supported, but Web Chat v4 is compatible with v3 bots. Take a look at the [Migration](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#migrating-from-web-chat-v3-to-v4) documentation for more details.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is possible to do this in v3 Web Chat (and if requested, I can share)...however, it's a moot point as trying to call close.window() from a script is blocked by nearly all browsers due to security risks. For reference, Mozilla [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) state a script can only close a window if the same script also opened that window. In both v3 and v4, this attempt to close will fail.

Comment: @StevenKanberg add an answer with the v3 solution